# File I/O in Functions?

Tags: c++, function, file-io

I am trying to figure out how to correctly make a File I/O Function in C++, however I can not seem to get it to work properly. I am currently not at the level to use vectors yet. 
How would I go about changing this code to make it into a working function?

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Here is the Prototype:

```
string obtain_inFileName(void);
```

The Function Call:

```
 inputFileName = obtain_inFileName();
```

The Function:

```
string obtain_inFileName(void) 
{
 string inFile;

 cout<<"Enter the name of the input file: ";
 cin >> inFile;
 cout << endl;

 return (inFile); 
}
```

Comment: `cout` and `cin` are standard output and standard input. You use an `ifstream` in the same way you would use `cin`.

Comment: And how's `obtain_inFileName` actually declared/defined please?!?

Comment: Wow that code is filled up with so many misconceptions, I'm still struggling with which of them to star off.

Comment: sorry I rewrote the code and did not copy and paste. I edited it. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @NinjaZ _"Hopefully that helps."_ No, it certainly doesn't. `return;` is certainly (blatantly) wrong! Please go back to your text book and look up for the basics!

Comment: @crashmstr yes, but I am trying to ask the user for a name of the inputfile.

Comment: @NinjaZ if you want a string from the user, you don't need to pass a `ifstream`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thats a little harsh, like i said I wrote this quick and i'm pretty new to C++...

Comment: @crashmstr thanks I didn't know that ill try and figure it out from there and post any updates.

Comment: @NinjaZ There is no file I/O here. You're asking the user to input a file name, which will be a `std::string`. Thus there is no need for an `ifstream`, which is used to interact with files.

Comment: @NinjaZ _"thats a little harsh ..."_ **No!** Feel beloved! Telling people the plain truth is much better, than letting them dream along :-P

Comment: I think I fixed the issue I was having thanks to everyones comments. I edited the code in my question to reflect what I now have. If anyone else has any opinions or suggestions feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the closest thing I could consider working for your case would be

```
string obtain_inFileName (ifstream &inFileName) {
 std::string inputFileName;
 cout<<"Enter the name of the input file: ";
 cin>>inputFileName;
 inFileName.open(inputFileName.c_str());
 return inputFileName;
}
```

Not claiming, that this is a good implementation!